I copy the mesh with the same material and scale it, the scaled one looks different

The one in red circle is original source, and I scaled the one in yellow circle. How can i fix this issue?

Have you applied the scale to the objects and UV unwrapped them?

yes I did but it seem the texture still looks different

Hello please pack your image and share the file (the 2 objects only)

Adjust your UVs.

@moonboots , I only can upload .blend file, here is the link to the texture: https://polyhaven.com/a/wood_table_001

Your problem is you need to adjust UVs, or use generated coords.
Right now you took a mesh that looks like this.

And then scaled it up only in the 3D viewport side of things.

Scaling it by that same amount in the UV coords fixes the problem.

You can also use Box Projection w/ Object coordinates in the shader to have your texture auto project to your object. Might be useful here, but it also might introduce seams and stuff that you won't have control over. It all depends.



I'm not seeing the same thing if I open your file and load the image textures, anyway the problem I see is that the UVs of the small object are not proportional. See the UVs for the long object, it seems proportional:

While for the small object it doesn't seem proportional, so simply unwrap again, maybe even unwrap both the 2 objects at the same time to keep a coherent proportion of the texture:

